# How to format percentage?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, percentage, sql-query-store

I need help in formatting percentages. My original reason for formatting is that I want to display percentages near zero as 0.05% and not as .05%

So I did this:

```
IF (a.TOTAL <> 0 AND b.mkt <> 0) THEN
    v_perc := TO_CHAR(ROUND(100-( a.TOTAL*100/ b.mkt),2),'00.99') || '%';
END IF;
```

`v_perc`  is stored as `varchar2(50)`, but the formatting is not always as I need it.

When the percentage is below 10%. I get like 08.52 or 00.35%. But I want a format where the output is like 0.52%, 5.32%, 55%, 0%, 100%. I tried with `000.999` but that will give 000.000%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`TO_CHAR(<your_value>,'fm990D00','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')`

as your formatting model.

It satisfies your needs upto  is `100`( `100%` ). Apart from percentage, if your need more digits  in another case such as `11,115.54`, you can convert the second argument to `'fm999G990D00'`.

Comment: Hi,   have one more doubt,If I have to display the same thing for a column having number datatype (removing the appending of '%' part in the above formaula),what should be the datatype and formula,i tried decimal (5,2) and decimal (5,4) but when I remove the tochar format mentioned in the above solution and tried various formats but it is not giving the solution like above ,pl help

Comment: @karthikadiga trying to explain as far as I understoood, whenever <your_value> is `8.5`, you need `'fm990D00'` to convert to `8.50`, `'fm990D0000'`  to convert to `8.5000`. That is, you need `to_char` for conversion, otherwise it stands as `8.5`.

Comment: @karthikadiga hm OK, you can declare `perc` as `number(10,2)` or `number` or `float`.